# ivirabyan/jquery-mentions how to check ajax request respone

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using ivirabyan/jquery-mentions in my project. i can do ajax request, but the problem is how can i use the response

```
$('textarea.mentions').mentionsInput({
    source: function( request, response ) {

        $.ajax({
            url: rootPath() + "user/tagFriends/" + request.term,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",

            success: function(data){
              alert(data);
              // found data here
            }
        });
    },
    showAtCaret: true

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your server side code? i you're using php you need to make sure you use `json_encode` when printing out your response. the response is sent back as plain text but it still needs to be in the json format

Comment: my server side code was fine but not working on client side code. however i got my answer by Snehasish Sarker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code, it may work

```
$('textarea.mentions').mentionsInput({
source: function( request, response ) {

    $.ajax({
        url: rootPath() + "user/tagFriends/" + request.term,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(data){
          response(data);
          // Just add this line
        }
    });
},
showAtCaret: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: rootUrl + '/your_controller/',
            type: "GET",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            // YOUR DATA COMING FROM THE VIEW TO THE CONTROLLER (IF IT NEED IT).
            data: "{ 'id':'" + id + "', 'user': '" +user+ "'}",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                if (result) {
                 //DO YOUR STUFF. FOR EXAMPLE. SHOWING A DIV
                 $('#your_div').append("<div>Hi there. Controller send this: "+data+"</div>");
                 // IF YOR DATA IS AN OBJECT. YOU CAN ACCESS DIRECTLY.
                 // data.attribute1, data.attribute2,...
                 // EQUALS FOR A LIST OF OBJECT AFTER LOOP IT.
                } else {
                  //DO YOUR STUFF
                }
            },
            failure: function (data) {
                // DO YOR STUFF IN FAILURE CASE.
            },
        });
```

Comment: sorry, you didn't understand my question. but thanks for reply

Comment: If you set the values correctly, this method let you use the response coming from the server:
success: function (result) {}
That was your question, wasnt?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use jQuery for the ajax part: it worked for me.

```
$('textarea.mentions').mentionsInput({
    source: function(request, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
                } else {
                    callback([]);
                }
            }
        }
        xhr.open('GET', '/ajax.php?search=' + encodeURIComponent(request.term));
        xhr.send();
    },
    showAtCaret: true
});
```

ajax.php :

```
$answer = 
    array(
        array(
            'value' => 'alex',
            'uid' => 'user:1',
        ),
        array(
            'value' => 'andrew',
            'uid' => 'user:2',
        ),
        array(
            'value' => 'vincent',
            'uid' => 'user:3',
        ),
    
    );
echo json_encode($answer);
```